# PhoneGap - Barcode Scanner (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, barcode, barcode-scanner, phonegap-plugins

I'm getting a basic droid error with the barcode scanner for Phonegap. I'm sure its a simple fix, or something that i'm missing. I can't seem to put my finger on it. I have imported com.google.zxing.client.android.R

Error Code:

```
04-29 05:49:38.448: E/AndroidRuntime(12450): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.client.android.R$layout
04-29 05:49:38.448: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:156)
04-29 05:49:38.448: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-29 05:49:38.448: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-29 05:49:38.448: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-29 05:49:38.448: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-29 05:49:38.448: E/AndroidRuntime(12450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
```

Capture Activity Lines

```
super.onCreate(icicle);

Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
#156 --> setContentView(R.layout.capture);

CameraManager.init(getApplication());
viewfinderView = (ViewfinderView) findViewById(R.id.viewfinder_view);
resultView = findViewById(R.id.result_view);
statusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_view);
```

Comment: Check if the zxing library is specified in project settings. It looks like zxing lib was not deployed along with your app.

Comment: This is actually inside the barcode library itself. The barcode library is added to my project and added as a lib.

Comment: Did you follow my tutorial on getting this installed? http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2011/12/installing-barcode-plugin-for-phonegap.html

Comment: @SimonMacDonald Thank you! I actually followed a separate tutorial. One of the steps to link the library was missing and I overlooked that. This solved that issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem again and I can't believe I never posted an answer. I'm sorry, well heres the answer.

You need to add the lib to your eclipse project and ensure that "Is Library" is checked. But then you need to add the zxing library as a reference in your app, as so.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check For library and jar file that had been added to your project 
 Zxing project should be set as Library to your project

1. Click Properties on project
2. Check Is Library 
   Jar File Required for Zxing project is Core.jar

In Your App

1. Click Properties
2. Click Add Library
3. Select the Zxing project

Jar File Required for your app beside Xzing is SupportV4,Core.jar

In Android Studio 
Open Project Structure (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S)
On Library Tab Add Required Jar File to your specific project 
On Module Tab add project dependency (Zxing) to set it as Library project

Answer (score 0):

```
NoClassDefFoundError
```

sounds like a library is missing, I got a problem with my libraries in my projects after the last update and the error was the same. Does it works before?

Comment: This is actually inside the library. I'm trying to get it to work properly. The function call gets into the library itself which is where the undefined comes from.

Comment: .. but that doesn't mean somehow that you aren't missing files from the library. That's what this indicates.

Comment: that is exactly what i got, could you try to open your project on a other pc or create a new user on your PC and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a layout (probably for the screen you see when scanning a barcode) is missing from the resources of your project as deployed.

It would be worth going back over the instructions for incorporating zxing in your application - probably a step has been missed.